# What does 'adb forward internal error mean?

Tags: android, cmd, adb

i have one device attached to pc having usb device enabled(from developer option) im trying to send command line forward to device like this

```
   adb -d forward tcp:5037 tcp:5037
```

but gives

```
internal error
```

and don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Because most probably port 5037 is used by `adb` itself.
Check how `adb` was started and you will see

```
adb -P 5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 4
```

Use a different port.

Comment: shall i must use different ports ??

Comment: -d forward tcp:1234 tcp:1235 i mean like this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: im trying to create a tcp client between c# application and adb using TCPClient and forward command